# Cannot seem to work out how to remove childNodes properly

Tags: javascript, html

So I have build a little display. If you click on a filter word it is supposed to display a tag.
Thats working so far . Thats the first code snippet.

But If I click on the filter word I want it to be removed from the document again and I cant figure that out. That would be the second function. I want to iterate thorugh the created "display" elements and remove them again if they contain the "clicked value" area. The out commented stuff did not work I either get the error that leng is not a function or that he "cannot read property 0 of undefined at tagFunction".

Thank you for your help !

```js
var area = event.target.textContent;                             
var spa = document.createElement("span");
var p = document.createElement("p");
spa.setAttribute('class', 'display');
p.setAttribute("class", "display1")
var text = document.createTextNode(area);                                      
spa.appendChild(p);
p.appendChild(text);
p.addEventListener("click", tagFunction);
document.getElementById("tags123").appendChild(spa);
```

```html
<div class="tags123" id="tags123">

</div>
```

```js
function tagFunction() {

    var area = event.target.textContent; 
             
    var leng = document.getElementsByClassName("display1");
    var tags123 =document.getElementsByClassName("tags123");
 
    for(var ll = 0;ll<leng.length;ll++){
        if(leng[ll].innerText.trim().contains(area)){
            //tags123.removeChild(leng(ll));
            tags123.children[ll].remove();
            // leng(ll).remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May you put the code together in the code snippet and fix the syntax error so we can run it? Thank you.

Comment: Its code for a widget that you drag onto a site. I will not be able to reproduce it here fully.But I think the code is enough. What are you not understanding ?

Comment: @Bitlord Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' on first snippet!

Comment: I have found the error thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This was the error. I had to declare parentNode of the leng[ll] element first.

```
             if(leng[ll].innerText.trim().contains(bereich)){
                 var vader = leng[ll].parentNode;
                 document.getElementById("tags123").removeChild(vader);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two error in two lines:

`if(leng[ll].innerText.trim().includes(area)){  //should be contains and not includes`

`leng(ll).remove(); // should be [ ] and not ( )`

it will be like this:

`if(leng[ll].innerText.trim().contains(area)){`

`leng[ll].remove();`

```js
var area = "text test";                             
            var spa = document.createElement("span");
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            spa.setAttribute('class', 'display');
            p.setAttribute("class", "display1")
            var text = document.createTextNode(area);                                      
            spa.appendChild(p);
            p.appendChild(text);
            p.addEventListener("click", tagFunction);
            document.getElementById("tags123").appendChild(spa);




function tagFunction() {

            var area = event.target.textContent; 
             
             var leng = document.getElementsByClassName("display1");
             var tags123 =document.getElementsByClassName("tags123");
             console.log(leng);
             for(var ll = 0 ; ll <= leng.length; ll++){
                 if(leng[ll].innerText.trim().includes(area)){
                    leng[ll].remove();
                 }
             }
  }
```

```html
 <div class="tags123" id="tags123">

  </div>
```